# Django problems with tinymce

Tags: django, tinymce

I create a directory named 'js' in my media root then create 'tiny_mce' and copy scrpits from TinyMCE(tiny_mce.js is in this directory) to this folder. Next I create texareas.js in 'js' directory which this code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

// Theme options
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,fullscreen,code",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl",

theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
theme_advanced_resizing : true,

// Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
//content_css : "/css/style.css",

template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

// Style formats
style_formats : [
    {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'strong'},
    {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
    {title : 'Help', inline : 'strong', classes : 'help'},
    {title : 'Table styles'},
    {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow'}
],

width: '700',
height: '400'
});
```

I have in my settings.py:

`TINYMCE_JS_URL = MEDIA_URL + 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'

TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = MEDIA_ROOT + 'js/tiny_mce'

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {

    'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",

    'theme': "advanced",

}

TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True

TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = False

TINYMCE_FILEBROWSER = False`

In models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce import models as tinymce_models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    class Media:
        js = ("/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js", "/js/textareas.js")
```

And in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import *

admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

But I still don't have TinyMCE Editor but only standard editing options in admin panel. My django version is 1.2. I spend 2 days and it is going too be hard to clear thinking about this in this moment. Is there something missing in my admin.py or what? Could someone can help?

**Answer:**
**Ok. I have the answer. The problem was because of in my settings i had `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl'` but i don't have installed package with this language. Stupid little thing but very important**

Comment: Why don't you actually post that as the answer, and accept it, instead of editing the question? That's typically how we do it on SO